# .htaccess (?) problem with missing slash after subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm new here so sorry for mistakes!

I got Wordpress webpage "domain.com" and second wordpress webpage "domain.com/en/" it's whole new WP system in subfolder.

Problem is when i write "domain.com/en" without last slash it directs me into "domain.com", when i add that slash and try "domain.com/en/" it directs me to that second page.

I think it might be problem with .htaccess, but not really sure.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.4]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Which should be default .htaccess

in the /en directory i got .htaccess looking like this

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.4]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /en/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

To be honest i dont know if this one is doing something.

And main problem is... When im on "domain.com/en/" and click on menu logo it got url without last slash "domain.com/en" and directs me into second web.

Hopefully it's understandable.
Thanks for your help and your time!
And have a nice day!

Comment: So, you don't just have two separate WordPress pages, you have two entirely separate WordPress installs... one in the root and one in the `/en` subdirectory?

Comment: yes, exactly like that...